# Creating a back button with image in XIB file

Tags: ios, iphone

I want to design the [back button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lS1YR.png) similar to screen design attached. On click of back button home screen appears. How can I do it? Note: without using navigation bar

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO! What have you tried so far? There are lots of good tutorials and examples on the web on how to style your buttons in iOS. What did you look at, what didn't work for you?

Comment: Hi i just take label and in the label i drop a button and then how to button act like back button

Answer (score 0):

Use following code to create button.

```
UIButton yourButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[yourButton setTitleColor:[UIColor whiteColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[yourButton setTitle:@"BACK" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[yourButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"back_arrow_image_name.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[yourButton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"bg_image_name.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[yourButton addTarget:self action:@selector(backButtonClicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];



-(void)backButtonClicked:(UIButton*)sender
{
     //code for navigate to home page
}
```